# User input ending loops on C++

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to create something (I'm thinking probably a loop?) that will allow me to have the user enter several numbers and then enter something like "done" to get all the numbers added up.

for example if I have a float (call it x for now) they could enter "7 *enter* 5 *enter* 9 *enter* done *enter*" and it would add those numbers and make x that value. Where I am coming into problems is that I need the user to be able to be able to enter as many numbers as they want (between 1 and 70 as an example) without specifying how many numbers they want to enter, just entering something in when they are done.

Thank you all

Comment: Can the ending input be the end of file (ctrl-z on Windows, ctrl-d on UNIX)?

Comment: This sounds like homework, in such cases 0 is used(or -1 if 0 is valid input) to terminate the input loop

Comment: What you're looking for is a while loop, but it becomes a bit shorter if the above condition is ok and you don't need to make sure it won't break.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use an infinite loop (`while (true)` or `for (;;)`) to read the next input into a string.

Check if the string is `done`. If so, `break` the loop.

Then try to parse that string into a `double` (don't use `float`) with the function `std::stod`.

If the parsing fails, optionally print an error message like `"Bad input, try again"` and restart the loop. If the parsing succeeds, add the number to the counter and restart the loop.